# Trigonometric Identities: Given $\tan(2a)=2$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}<a<2\pi$ find value of $\tan(a)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given $\tan(2a)=2$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}<a<2\pi$ find value of $\tan(a)$

I first found the values of $\cos(2a)$ and $\sin(2a)$ and then used the half angle formula.

$$\tan(a)=\tan\frac{2a}{2}=\frac{1-\cos(2a)}{\sin(2a)}
\implies\frac{5}{2\sqrt 5}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{5}}5\right)$$

I then simplified that to $\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}-1$

Then because it is in fourth quadrant I multiplied by negative 1 and got:

$$1-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Am I doing something wrong, or am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the double-angle identity.
$$\tan(2a) = \frac{2\tan{a}}{1-\tan^2(a)}$$

$$\implies \frac{2\tan{a}}{1-\tan^2(a)} = 2$$

$$\implies 2\tan{a} = 2-2\tan^2{a} \implies \tan{a} = 1-\tan^2{a} \implies \tan^2{a}+\tan{a}-1 = 0$$

Set $t = \tan{a}$ and solve for $t$.

$$t^2+t-1 = 0$$

$$t = \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Plug in $\tan{a}$.

$$\tan{a} = \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

But $\frac{3\pi}{2} < a < 2\pi$, so $\tan{a} < 0$.

$$\tan{a} = \frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Comment: THANK YOU, I SEE MY mistake, <3

Comment: That <3 is supposed to be a heart.

Comment: Well, glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

use the well known formula

$$\tan(2a)=\frac{2\tan(a)}{1-\tan^2(a)}=2$$

and $$\tan(a)<0.$$

You need to solve

$$\tan^2(a)+\tan(a)-1=0$$

to find
$$\tan(a)=\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Comment: why is tan(a)>0 ? Sorry

Comment: @SavvasNicolaou Sorry. it is negative.

Comment: Oh ok, because it is 4th quadrant correct?

Comment: @SavvasNicolaou Yes of course. the tangent is negative in second and fourth quadrant.

Comment: My book says that, that answer is incorrect.

Comment: But it looks right to me...

Comment: Oh that is not what I got.

Comment: I solved that quadratic and got 1 and -2

Comment: @SavvasNicolaou How did you find $\cos(2a)$.

Comment: @SavvasNicolaou No. look i gave the correct answer.

Comment: I used a triangle, and said that if tan(2a) = 2, then cos(2a)=√5/5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84993/discussion-between-savvas-nicolaou-and-hamam-abdallah).

Comment: @SavvasNicolaou It is late here . i go to bed.

Answer (score 0):

You made two mistakes, but your method does work.

If $\tan(2a)=2$, then either

Case 1:  $0< 2a +2 n \pi<\pi/2$, $\cos(2a)=1/\sqrt{5}$, and $\sin(2a)= 2/\sqrt{5}$ (first quadrant),  or

Case 2:  $\pi<2a+2 n \pi<3 \pi/2$, $\cos(2a)=-1/\sqrt{5}$, and $\sin(2a)= -2/\sqrt{5}$ (third quadrant)

for some integer $n$.

The problem stated that $3 \pi/2 < a < 2 \pi$, so  $3 \pi < 2 a < 4 \pi$ and that puts us in Case 2 with $n=-1$.

Now using your method
$$\tan(a)=\frac{1 - \cos(2 a)}{\sin(2 a)} = \frac{1+1/\sqrt{5}}{-2/\sqrt{5}}
=  - \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}.
$$